# Change Categories Google Drive via API

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

In Google Drive folders, it exists file properties. These properties has an item named "categories" whitch has own properties. These "Categories" are creating by Dominium Administrators (Categories and own properties), users assign some of these Categories to files and they fill in the categories values.

We want to automate the assign and fill in the files but we can't find how could we do it.

We use Google Drive API REST requeted from a python aplication, to copy and change files in Google Drive, but "categories" isn't a selectable Field.

Anyone could help us about how can we change by Drive API REST "categories"?(python code but in Google Script it's OK too)